# How can I max value and min value for a number data type in the creation of a table in oracle

Tags: oracle, numbers, create-table

I want to set score number to be maximum 100 and minimum 0. Am I right with just giving score number 3 placements, 3 digits and that is already enough as long as I don't looks for a number larger than 100 with NO decimal places.

```
create table grades (
S varchar2(12),
C varchar2(10),
Score number(3),
Letter_Grade char(1)
Constraint PK_grades Primary Key (S)
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a check constraint:

```
create table myTable (
      a number check (a between 0 and 100),
      b number
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to allow decimal places?  If not specify the precision too

```
Score number(3, 0),
```

The other thing is, `number(3)` will allow a range of -999 to 999.  So you need to add a check constraint.  Something like this

```
constraint CK_grades check ( score between 0 and 100 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a NUMBER(3) would work (assuming integers only)

You could also add a CHECK constraint on the column.

```
ALTER TABLE GRADES ADD CONSTRAINT GRADES_SCORE_CHECK CHECK (SCORE BETWEEN 0 AND 100);
```